# Differentiate between GCM and C2DM ids

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I'm migrating my app from C2DM to GCM but the server on which i'll be sending the registration id will still be entertaining C2DM ids. So my question is what can I do from my app so that server can identify that this is GCM id. Google recommends to send a new bit along with registration id. How can I do that. Please give an exmaple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do if you're not using AppEngine.

In your server, you should already have a table that stores all the registration id (reg_id). You need to add another column to this table, say 'is_gcm_reg_id'. You would default all existing rows to '0' for this column since they are currently all C2DM reg_ids. You could also just create a new table to store the GCM reg_ids, if you like.

Then in your GCM enabled application, you just need to let your server know the reg_id is a GCM reg_id. You didn't mention how you upload the reg_id to your server (Web Service call? Simple POST request?). If using Web Service call, just create a new method that will be used exclusively by your new GCM-enabled app. If using POST request, just add another key value pair like 'gcm=true' and your server should look for this kvp.

Finally, you should have all the pieces needed to know the reg_id is of GCM, and update the 'is_gcm_reg_id' column field (or a new GCM table) accordingly.

Comment: Hey Thanks..thats good way..will try... and i'm using web service call

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using App Engine to implement GCM/C2DM.

In the deviceInfo entity for your App Engine there is already a "type" field. This is the field you will modify to either say "ac2dm" or "gcm".

An easy way to do this is to create a new registration request that simply passes "gcm" instead of "ac2dm". Take a look in your AppEngine project and locate the RegistrationInfo class. Look at the register() method. Simply replace "ac2dm" with "gcm".

**EX:**

```
     // original
 public void register() {
    log.info("register " + this);
    try {
      doRegister(getDeviceRegistrationId(), "ac2dm", getDeviceId(), getAccountName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.info("Got exception in registration: " + e + " - " + e.getMessage());
      for (StackTraceElement ste : e.getStackTrace()) {
        log.info(ste.toString());
      }
    }
    log.info("Successfully registered");
  }

      // new version
     public void register() {
    log.info("register " + this);
    try {
      doRegister(getDeviceRegistrationId(), "gcm", getDeviceId(), getAccountName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.info("Got exception in registration: " + e + " - " + e.getMessage());
      for (StackTraceElement ste : e.getStackTrace()) {
        log.info(ste.toString());
      }
    }
    log.info("Successfully registered");
  }
```

You will probably have to recompile the RPC service to get this to work.

Now, it's up to you to make sure your server checks for the "gcm" tag of the deviceInfo entity and acts accordingly. Also, read this if you haven't seen it https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html